# VB.NET tableadapter returns integer value instead of text

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, datatable, tableadapter

I'm trying to show a messagebox with the users first name from a dataset but I keep getting an integer returned.

Below is the code I'm currently using to get a 1 returned.  The datatable only contains 1 column named "Name" and it is set as a system.string if that helps.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
MessageBox.Show(FirstNameTableAdapter.Fill(DsUsers.FirstNameTable, Environment.UserName), "User")
End Sub
```

I just feel like it's something very easy I'm missing.

Comment: Fill is a function that returns the number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function call of `FirstNameTableAdapter.Fill(DsUsers.FirstNameTable, Environment.UserName)` will fill the DataTable `FirstNameTable` with the result of its associated CommandText. It's return value will be number of rows it has loaded.

What I think you want to be doing is calling this line separately

```
FirstNameTableAdapter.Fill(DsUsers.FirstNameTable, Environment.UserName)
```

And then calling the message box

```
MessageBox.Show(DsUsers.FirstNameTable.Rows(0)("Name"), "User")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you.